# How can I create this structure of named objects in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose, database

Right now, I'm using **Firebase** with a structure like this. I am **switching to MongoDB** so I can have more complex queries.

```
{
  leagues: {
    'a': { players, teams },
    'b': { players, teams }
  }
}
```

Players, teams, etc will all have models. They will be inside user created leagues.

**How would I make this structure in MongoDB where these leagues contain collections of teams, and players?**

Thanks for the help just starting out in mongodb.

Comment: In this case, I think it would be easier to use multiple collections rather than embedded documents. You could have a collection for leagues, players, and teams. Each league would consist of an array of player ID references and an array of team ID references. Each player would consist of its own set of properties, and same for teams. You would then change your `leagues` to be an array of league ID references. Because even if you do achieve to get it working, querying or updating would be headache. This is a [good read](http://openmymind.net/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have two different collections with a one to many relation

or

Embed the players inside the team.

It is upto you how it suits you. Consider your queries and evaluate your indexes before deciding the structure